# absolute positioned child overlaps parent scroll bar

Tags: css

I have a parent div with two child div(header and body), I want to set header position fixed on top and only body should scroll.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="body">Body</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #333;
overflow: auto;
}
.header {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: #ccc;
}
.body {
height: 300px;
background: #999;
margin-top: 101px;
}
```

I found the header div overlaps parent div's scroll bar. I can't set parent div position as relative because I want header position fixed. I can't set header position as 'fixed' because this content avilable somewhere middle of the page.

How can I avoid absolute positioned child not overlaps parent's scroll bar?

Find jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T43eV/1/

Comment: why you can't have header position:fixed?

Comment: position: fixed also give similar result as position: absolute.

Answer (score 3):

The overflow property should be set on the `.body`, not `.box`, as such : http://jsfiddle.net/T43eV/8/

Comment: I want the scroll for box and body should scroll behind header.

Comment: What do you mean? Box contains header, so if you scroll "behind" header, that goes back to your original situation.

Comment: What I am expecting is the header should not overlaps the scroll bar as like if I set .box { position: relative; }. But I want the header always visible on top and should not scroll when I scroll box.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
.box { position:relative; }
```

**EDIT:** There isn't any need to use `absolute` anyway, remove that and put `overflow:auto` on `.body`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yp9JJ/)

```
.box {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.body {
    height: 200px;
    background: #999;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**EDIT:** I don't think you can do this consistently across platforms. You could kind of do it by setting your `right` property on .header to be as large at the scrollbar, but the size of the scrollbar is bound to the operating system and isn't a single size.

You could look into an `iframe` as that will create a page within your page, scrollbar and all.

Comment: I can't set .box { position: relative; } because it makes the header also scroll. I am expecting similar result but header should not scroll.

Comment: I want the scroll bar for box, header should always visible on top and when I scroll box only body should scroll.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps set z-index:-1 in .header and the header will not overlap the scroll bar.

```
Here is the working fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T43eV/28/

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be by using a [sticky position](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/position). This will keep the header inside the scrollable div but won't make it overlap the scroll (or get behind the scroll if you set a lower z-index)

```
.box {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    overflow: auto;
}
.header {
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.body {
    height: 300px;
    background: #999;
    margin-top: 101px;
}
```

However this is [not supported by internet explorer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)